# Pre-deployment conditions : OR condition before stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Based on the latest build I would like to deploy one of the test environments(There are many test environments). Will choose test environment during the release then deploy into pre-prod and PROD environments if test deployment is a success.

How to add Pre-deployment conditions if one of the deployment is a success in the triggers?

For example, we have 4 test environments(parallel stages like below). First I would like to deploy in TEST1. If the TEST1 stage is a success then deploy into PRE-PROD then PROD.

[image]

When I created the release, I changed TEST2, TEST3, TEST4 to manual as I need to deploy into only TEST1. but PRE-PROD is still waiting for TEST2, TEST3 and TEST4 to be succeed.

[image]

Tried: Added dependency on all 4 stages(TEST environments), PRE-PROD is waiting for all 4 need to succeed.

Comment: In the PRE-PROD trigger choose "After Stage" and choose the TEST1 stage.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, Tried that as well, here we need to change the condition for every release.

Comment: I don't understand. do you want pre-prod will run if test1 will success? if yes, why pre-prod depend on test2/3/4?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, As I mentioned above, we have a pool of test environments and we deploy in one of the test environment based on the changes. but we need to deploy in all changes in PRE-PROD and PROD.